# Ruby: how to do change object to something readable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-geocoder

I'm using the geocoder gem which has the ability to pick up IP address from an http request. from the documentation:

```
Geocoder adds a +location+ method to the standard <tt>Rack::Request</tt> object so you can easily look up the location of any HTTP request by IP address. For example, in a Rails controller or a Sinatra app:

 # returns Geocoder::Result object
  result = request.location
```

I put

```
@result = request.location
```

in my controller and then in my view

```
<%= @result %>
```

However, I got this.

```
#<Geocoder::Result::Freegeoip:0x00000102dc7758>
```

I then tried

```
<%= @result.to_s %>
```

but it didn't change anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: The [`request.location` return value](http://rubydoc.info/gems/geocoder/Geocoder/Result/Freegeoip) has various methods, you could try using those.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't it strange that ip_address isn't one of those methods? the address method seems to be a physical address.

Comment: `request.ip`, at least that's what they say http://www.rubygeocoder.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is an IP address, then you can get that from the request headers. It may not be perfectly accurate due to spoofing, but from a quick look at some of the header values, I found the REMOTE_ADDR to contain mine. Just put this in a controller. If someone else can recommend other or better values to use, please let us know.

```
request.headers['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

I actually tried checking for HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR, but it didn't exist in the headers. Perhaps webrick doesn't use it.

Comment: **Note**: it's not that simple! It's even simpler! :) Check my answer!

Answer (score 3):

To get the IP of a client use `request.ip`. It's more correct way of getting the IP, **especially when your user is behind a proxy**. So, it's simple as:

```
 request.ip
```

Here's its source:

```
 # File lib/rack/request.rb, line 256
 def ip
   if addr = @env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']
     (addr.split(',').grep(/\d\./).first || @env['REMOTE_ADDR']).to_s.strip
   else
     @env['REMOTE_ADDR']
   end
 end
```